# Insert fails within transaction, but sql server returns 1 row(s) affected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is the execution flow of my `stored procedure`:

```
ALTER procedure dbo.usp_DoSomething

as

declare @Var1 int
declare @Var2 int
declare @Var3 int

select 
@Var1 = Var1,
@Var2 = Var2,
@Var3 = Var3
from Table
where  
...

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        /* UPDATE Table. This executes successfully */

        /* INSERT Table. This fails due to PK violation */

        COMMIT TRAN /* This does not happen */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN /* This occurs because TRANS failed */
END CATCH
```

The `UPDATE` runs successfully. The `INSERT` fails, so the `transaction` is rolled back.

After execution, the table looks correct and nothing has changed. But when I run the SP, I get the following messages:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

So I'm asking myself, where is the first `1 row(s) affected` coming from?

Then I'm thinking that this is the reason, but wanted to confirm: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
An UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement that has an OUTPUT clause will return
rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and is rolled back.
The result should not be used if any error occurs when you run the statement.
```

Comment: But why not report the error for the `INSERT`? Instead it says `0 row(s) affected`. It's sort of misleading.

Comment: You have an anti-pattern here that I call try-squelch. You went to the trouble of catching an exception but then you just carry on as though nothing happened. This type of thing is incredibly difficult to debug. The rollback is fine but you need to rethrow your exception so you know it happens and have some idea what error did happen.

Comment: @rbhatup: it does report the error on `INSERT`, but as Sean said you just catch it and do nothing with it.

Comment: I understand that I don't do anything with the error. What I don't seem to understand is why the return message changes from the red `Msg 2601 - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object` to `0 row(s) affected` with the use of `TRANS` keyword.

Comment: Or at least,  that it returns a `0 row(s) affected` and then a message saying that a `ROLLBACK` took place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a rowcount will be returned for every DML statement, unless `SET NOCOUNT ON` is enabled.  Regardless whether a transaction is successful or not, or rolled back or committed, your UPDATE statement was successful, thus the notification `(1 row(s) affected)`.

The `OUTPUT` clause you mentioned has nothing to do with it, since you haven't specified it.

Comment: What I don't seem to understand is why the return message changes from the red `Msg 2601 - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object`  to `0 row(s) affected` with the use of `TRANS`.

Comment: Or at least, `0 row(s) affected` and then a message saying that a `ROLLBACK` took place.

Comment: The update statement created the "1 row affected", the failed insert statement created the "0 row affected".

Answer (score 0):

The first select with setting variables could produce 1 row affected

Comment: It doesn't. I created the SP with just that `SELECT`. When I run it I get `Command(s) completed successfully.`.